# <script> element not refreshing

Tags: html, jsp

I have a Java class that builds up a name/value pairs string that displays information in a JSP file. The data is added to the `<script>` element. E.g.

```
<script>Value 1</script>
<script>Value 2</script>
```

The values are populated from values in a form, when i hit a button called Search.

When I fill in the values and hit Search, I then inspect the page and see the correct values (as above). But, if I change the values (say change Value 2 to Value 3) and hit Search, the script elements remain the same.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: ummmm, quotes around tag names?

Comment: I've removed the quotation marks, the tags display just fine